# How do i cancel time count?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below it counts minutes and seconds if the toggle button is clicked.
Is it possible to make it cancel everything if its clicked/toggled, meaning that i can be able to clicked another toggle button.

```
function toggle(ths) {

    var clicked = $(ths).val();
    $("#lblType").html(clicked);
    $("#setCount").html(" minutes : " + minutes + " seconds : " + count);

       count = count + 1;
       if (count % 60 == 0) {
           minutes += 1;
           count = 0;
       }
        timer = setTimeout("toggle()", 1000);

    }




       <div ><label id="lblType"></label>
          <label id="setCount"></label>
     </div></p>
     <div id="planned"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout):

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: inside or outside the loop ?

Comment: @C_Major - If you're trying to cancel it on a click, it can't be from inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clearTimeout()`

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout

Comment: inside or outside the loop ?

Comment: @C_Major - outside.  You don't need to repeat the operation.

Answer (score 0):

`window.clearTimeout(timer)`

Check http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp for more info.

Answer (score 0):

By using `cleartimeout(); clearinterval();`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer=null;

function toggle(ths) {
    var clicked = $(ths).val();
    $("#lblType").html(clicked);
    $("#setCount").html(" minutes : " + minutes + " seconds : " + count);

       count = count + 1;
       if (count % 60 == 0) {
           minutes += 1;
           count = 0;
       }
        timer = setTimeout("toggle()", 1000);

    }

function quitTimer(){
  window.clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = null;
}
```

Comment: the your function  its does not seem to be working

Comment: which part of the function? i only added the quitTimer() function and the timer variable. the toggle function was the op's